# What does JSON.stringify() does with functions in an object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

Assuming a Javascript object has a function:

```
function Foo() {
    this.a = 32;
    this.bar = function (){
        alert("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

How does `JSON.stringify()` deal with the `bar` function? Is it just ignored? Is this standard practice? What does JSON converts and doesn't convert into the Json string?

**Rem:** I don't know why people downvoted my question, it is obvious one should not stringify an object with a function. I was just trying to understand the default behavior.

Comment: JSON is an ECMA Standard - what it does to what data types should be well specified.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R3K7e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) simply changes functions passed into `null` if passed into an array, and does not include the property in at all if in an object. It makes no attempt to replicate the function, not even in string form.

For example, see this:

```
JSON.stringify([function () {}]); // "[null]"
JSON.stringify({ x: function () {} }); // "{}"
```

If you attempt to stringify a function itself, it's not a valid JSON value, which means that `JSON.stringify` can't make a valid JSON string:

```
JSON.stringify(function () {}); // undefined
```

This is specified as part of the ECMAScript specification, though the actual wording of it is rather complex. However, a note is included that summarises this:

> NOTE 5
>
> Values that do not have a JSON representation (such as
>   **undefined** and functions) do not produce a String. Instead they produce the undefined value. In arrays these values are represented as
>   the String `null`. In objects an unrepresentable value causes the
>   property to be excluded from stringification.

Comment: It returns `undefined` for functions.

Comment: @MaxArt: JSON doesn't have `undefined`.

Comment: @MaxArt: Am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(function () {})); -> undefined`, `JSON.stringify([function () {}]); -> [null]`, you can however stringify functions by providing a custom replacer function  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/bzDXk/)

Comment: Yep, sorry, I was in a hurry when I wrote that comment :)